# Limit of Snedecor's F

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ such that $X\sim \dfrac{d}{n-d}F(d,n-d)$, with $d,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

What happens when $n\to\infty$? And when $d\to\infty$?

I think when $n\to\infty$ then it goes to 0, but I can not prove it.

Comment: Can you tell us in what context this question arises? Can you express X as the ratio of two independent chi-squared distributions?

Comment: Are you asking about the limit when $n\to \infty$ while $d$ remains fixed (resp. when $d\to \infty$ while $n$ remains fixed)?

Answer (score 0):

Comment:  This seems on the brink of being closed: for lack of
context, I would suppose. Are you studying, or about to study, ANOVA? As closure votes mount, one more hint.

Maybe as a start, use R to visualize the trend of the median of $X$ for increasing $n$.

```
 n = 11:200;  d = 10;  r = d/(n-d)
 h = qf(.5, d, n-d)*r
 plot(n, h, type="l")
```

[image]